# What is a Finite State Machine and What is it Used For?

Tags: javascript, state-machine

Recently, I've begun doing some research into Finite State Machines in JavaScript and I even [found a library](http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2013/1/26/javascript_state_machine_v2_2_0/) that makes them easier to implement. While I think I've grasped the idea that a state machine is used for tracking and changing the "state" of an object (e.g., 'ready', 'complete', 'inactive', etc.,), I don't think I fully understand the practical implications of them. Could someone please help by clarifying the following:

- What *exactly* is a finite state machine [or is it just called a state machine? I've heard it referred to both ways]?
- What are some practical uses for finite state machines (in JavaScript)?
- When would I *not* want to use an finite state machine?
- What books, articles, tutorials, etc., offer a more in-depth look at finite state machines (in JavaScript)?

Comment: Wikipedia? Google? Btw, note how JavaScript is merely a **scripting** language (i.e. it defines only the core API). So, the practical uses depend on the **environment** (web-browser, web-server, Win8), and not on the language itself.

Comment: I did in fact Google this. That's why I'd mentioned that I'd grasped the fact that a state machine is used to track "state" in an application but I'm having a hard time grasping the practical implications of this and am hoping someone could clarify.

Comment: Multi-step forms maybe?

Comment: Btw just ask the author of that JS library (there is a DISQUS section below the post) `:)` He should be able to give you a couple of examples.

Comment: A more advanced, open source JavaScript library for coding hierarchical state machines (UML statecharts) is available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/statechartjs/

Comment: I've also asked (and still am) myself similar questions. You may find this post useful: http://freshbrewedcode.com/jimcowart/2012/03/12/machina-js-finite-state-machines-in-javascript/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Finite State Machine is an abstract concept.  As such, the concept of state machine is orthogonal to any particular language.  If you [look at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), it says "is a mathematical model of computation used to design both computer programs and sequential logic circuits".

This means that FSM usually used as mathematical concept that is used by computer scientists to address questions with the discipline, like "can xyz be computed at all?"

Based on your question, and your link, I think you mean to ask about State Diagram (or Statechart) which is different.  When you create a state diagram, you are dividing your program in a series of states, and the events that can occur in those states.  For example, your program might be in the "EditingForm" state, receive the event "doSave", and then go into the "Saving" state, receive the event 'Save Complete", and go back into the "Viewing" state.

This abstraction is incredibly useful because it allows the programmer to conceptually organize what things should happen when, which when implemented correctly, leads to cleaner and more organized code.  This in turn leads to fewer bugs.  A state diagram, depending on the implementation, can prevent unintended effects by only handling the events defined for a state -- For example, the "Viewing" probably does not have a 'save' event defined, thus if the program is in the "Viewing" state any Save is meaningless, as that should only happen in the "Editing" state.

If you look at the overview of the framework to which you link, you will notice there are a bunch of handlers you can use to hook into entering states, leaving states, actions happening, etc.  This allows you to actually do things that correspond to the state/action.  For example, on entering the "Editing" state you might present the form to the user and enable the save button.  On entering the "Saving" state you might disable the button and fire a request to save.  On receiving the "SaveComplete" event you might transition to the "Viewing" state, remove the form, and show something else.

Comment: So the state machine manages "state" by tracking what the application is doing ("viewing" a page) and then either acting on or ignoring events that get fired (in JavaScript terms)? This almost sounds a lot like a controller (MVC) or an event-bus.

Comment: Its very similar.  In implementations I have used, you move thru your application by invoking events on the statechart, so it doesn't really track -- it is the point of entry for program control.

Comment: As I've been studying and using unidirectional data flow in client-side applications with Flux and particularly Redux, I've begun to understand that Redux is really helping you to use deterministic finite state machine to handle your UI state. In Redux, raised events are represented as actions, and reducer functions that are pure functions are like transition functions, that take the current state and the inputs from the raised events/actions, and create a new state, thus transitioning your UI to the next state.

Comment: Also, Redux seems to me to not just be any kind of FSM, but a deterministic FSM, meaning that for every action and inputs pair, there is only one UI state that can be transitioned to.

Answer (score 13):

> What is a finite state machine?

It is a way of declaring states and side effects of transitioning between them.

> What are some practical uses of finite state machines?

Instead of code like this:

```
function decide()
{
  if(mouseButtonIsDown && mouseIsMoving && mouseCoordinatesAreWithin(0, 0, 100, 100) && thePixelIsRed) {
    clearBuffers();
    startPlaying();
    cursorBecomeHand();
  }
  else if(!mouseButtonIsDown && !mouseIsMoving && mouseCoordinatesAreWithin(0, 0, 100, 100) && thePixelIsRed) {
    

  }
  // more ifs
}
```

You keep only a few states and break your events into functions, defining what happens in which state.

```
function drag_started() {
 switch(your_state) {
   case "within_box":
    clearBuffers();
    cursorBecomeHand();
    your_state= "playing";
    startPlaying();
    break;
 }
```

}

Which leads to the separation of states and events, which means less regressions and more maintainability.

> When would I not want to use an finite state machine?

Answers itself at this point. If you just have one state, don't bother with a state machine.

> What books, articles, tutorials, etc., offer a more in-depth look at finite state machines (in JavaScript)?

Against the academia, I recommend reading the source for jquery plugins. For example look under _mouseMove and _mouseUp in [the jquery ui source](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js)

Answer (score 3):

It is often used in the scanner and lexer of a language parser. Creating and then analyzing each token in the source code based on certain syntax rules.

Basically, here you check the current state to see if the next characters or tokens make sense and how they should be organized.

Comment: Ah yes, great example.